# Grails StaleObjectException during domain object save

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have already created a whole web application. I have started some load tests and sometimes I got `StaleObjectException`. 
I have interaction with database in several places and I would like not to change whole source code. My question is:

1. How without changes in code solve this problem?
2. If 1st is not possible, will moving database interaction code to Services solve the problem?
3. If 2nd is not possible, will changing transaction isolation level on database do the trick?
4. If 3rd is not possible, do you have any good solution for this problem?
5. Should I remove version from whole database and rely on database transactions?
6. Is caching good in my case or should I remove it from Hibernate configuration?

Comment: You should probably read up on why you are getting that exception before asking questions: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking

Comment: I know the reason. I am trying to find a solution.

Comment: The documentation states the solution.